# strpos always returns FALSE with wordpress post content

Tags: strpos

I am trying to search a string from wordpress post content and see if my substring is present or not. Following is the code

```
$closing_p = '</p>';
$paragraphs = explode($closing_p, $content);
$search_string="fdfd";
foreach($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph)
{
  if (strlen($search_string) > 0)
  {
    $posi =  strpos($paragraphs[$index],$search_string);
    if ($posi===FALSE)
    {
      $insert_ad = false;               
    }
    else
    {
      $insert_ad = true;
      echo "yessssss";
    }
  }
```

Content of wordpress post is 
"
Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!fdfdf"

But it always says not found . Any problems here

Comment: Try to 'echo' $paragraphs[$index] in the loop to see if it is the correct text where you want to search.

Comment: Yes, $paragraphs[$index] was not correct.. I was updating wrong file (which was backup ) and trying to execute .. Thanks ...